# Coloring 8x8 square board?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

A square board with side-length of 8 cm is divided
into 64 squares with side-length of 1 cm each. Each square can be painted black or
white. Find the total number of ways to color the board so that every square with
side-length of 2 cm formed with 4 small squares with a common vertex has two
black squares and two white squares.
After taking rhe hint ''Try to solve with columns''I did it by coloring first column in any way there are 2 ways for each square in a column thus $2^8$ ways then all other colorings have to bi fixed and this is where I am wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, write out your working and thought process to demonstrate where you're at.)

Consider the first column, with $2^8$ ways of coloring the squares (as you did).

**Hint:**  We can always extend the coloring to another column.

However, the extension need not be unique. When is it not unique? Find a necessary and sufficient condition.

> If (any) 2 consecutive squares are the same color, then it forces their neighbors in the next column to be of the opposite color. This then forces the rest of the column.
>  The row that the 2 consecutive squares have uniquely determined colors, which then forces the rest of the columns. Hence, there is a unique way to extend the coloring.

> Conversely, if no 2 conseuctive squares are of the same color, meaning the column is either BWBWBWBW or WBWBWBWB, then the next column is either BWBWBWBW or WBWBWBWB (only).

So, in the unique cases, each original way of coloring the column leads to (how many?) chessboards?

> 1

In the non-unique case, each original way of coloring the column leads to (how many?) chessboards.

> $2^7$.

Hence, the total number of ways is

> $(2^8 - 2) \times 1 + 2 \times 2^7 = 510.$

Comment: Sir there are $2^8$ ways if the coloring is non unique while I am getting $2^4$ ways for unique please tell where am I wrong

Comment: @Ken If it's unique, then there's only 1 way to extend the board. The (any) 2 consecutive squares of the same color must always remain consecutive squares of the same color in a given column, so there's only 1 way to extend it. If it's non-unique, we're adding 7 more columns, so there's $2^7$ ways.

Comment: This is correct.  More generally, $2^n-2$.

Comment: @RobPratt I got $2^{n+1} - 2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, my error.

Comment: can anyone give a more thorough explanation to why in the case where there's two consecutive squares of the same color on the first column this case gets $2^8-2$ colorings

Comment: Yeah but can you explain more why there's $2^8-2$ of the other cases, that's my question

Comment: I get that there's $2^8$ ways to color the first column but I don't really get how you're counting the other cases, can you explain those cases?

Comment: If there's no repeated square in the first column this means that the colors on this first one are either BWBWBWBW or WBWBWBWB so there's only two ways of coloring this first column in this case and alternating colors define that the colors on the next column are also alternating but oposite so wouldn't this result in only two colorings?

Comment: Or let me see if this thought process is ok

Because there's only two valid colorings when the first column has alternating colors then there's $2^8-2$ cases when this does not happen? Is that where that part comes from?

But if that's the case that would mean that we're counting the cases where there's at least two consecutive squares of the same color in the first column and we would be counting that other case? Or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @SamHaze Did you read the updated solution? It seems to me that you're confusing between the cases, and also whether you're counting the number of cases, or counting the number of solutions each "first column" results in. $\quad$ Case A: No repeated square - 2 ways to color the first column. How many ways to color the subsequent columns? Case B: Some repeated squares - How many ways to color the first column? How many ways to color the subsequent columns?

Comment: Yeah after some thought I realized that in case A there's still more cases than that, because a subsequent column can have repeated squares or it can be alternating, if it repeats a square then the subsequent columns are determined by this so there would be $2^7$ ways to color the subsequent columns right? So in case A there's $2^8$ total colorings and in case B, if there's a repeated square in the first column the coloring on the rest of the columns is determined by this, but as I'm counting there are $2^7$ colorings of the first column this way or why $2^8-2$?

Comment: Ohh no, in case B there's $2^8-2$ cases because the only times where the first column doesn't have repeated squares is when the coloring is either BWBWBWBW or WBWBWBWB right?

Comment: @SamHaze I disagree with your recent statement that "in case A there's still more cases than that, because a subsequent column **can have repeated squares** (it can't) or it can be alternating (yes it can, and in how many ways?)". . $\quad$ IMO You have most of the various bits needed, but are confused between 1) What are the cases exactly, 2) In each case, how many ways are there to color the first column, 3) In each case, given an initial first column, how many ways are there to color the rest? You have the correct numbers, but in the wrong context. EG You used $2^7$ twice, one time is wrong